# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll_system\php\function.php on line 118

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a warning and I can't find what the problem is. I am a little bit rusty now since I haven't coded since graduation.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll_system\php\function.php on line 118
>   not connected to database for fetching

here's the code for that line

```
$emps_checks="SELECT * FROM `information_tbl` WHERE `F_NAME` LIKE '$f_n' AND `M_NAME` LIKE '$m_n' AND `L_NAME` LIKE '$l_n'";
$checker_emp=mysqli_query($con,$emps_checks)or die("not connected to database for fetching");
$emp_result=mysqli_num_rows($checker_emp);
```

Comment: Post you full code, So that it will  be useful to trace easily

Comment: `$con` is a string not mysqli object, as the error suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your  `$con` should be

```
$con= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass, "mrmagicadam");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();exit;
}
```

Comment: _"You are combining mysql and mysqli"_ How do you figure that?

Comment: @Phil. Its a guess, at the beginning when i migrated from mysql mysqli, i got this error. rectified my answer. Please check

Comment: `or die` is no way to handle error conditions in this day and age

Comment: @Phil. Is that okay now ? Or anything else to be changed?

Comment: Personally, I'd throw an exception but then again, I'd set `mysqli_report()` to throw them automatically. There's nothing inherently wrong with your answer though (other than the fact that it will continue executing even if the DB connection fails)

Comment: @Phil. I understand, I added exit to my answer